# He is not the best student in this class

Tags: phrase-meaning

If you say, "He is not the best student in this class," do you mean "he is maybe the second or the third best student in this class" or " he is the worst student in this class" or anything else?

Comment: It's ambiguous. Negatives are like that. For instance, in a recommendation letter, if you say "I cannot recommend this student too highly", what do you expect the reader to think?

Answer (score 2):

**Without Context** , it means Exactly what it says : There is some other Student who is Better.
We can not know whether there are other worse Students or whether a lot of Students are Better than him.

**With Context** , it may mean a lot more :

**With Context 1** :

> Why did X get so low marks ? He is the "Best Student" in the School !
> He is NOT the best in school. He is not even the Best in his Class.

It is stating a fact , here.

**With Context 2** :

> Is X a moron ?
> Well , I would not like to put it that way. Let me say that he is not the Best Student in Class.

Euphemism to state that X is indeed a moron , here.

> Similar to " ... [not the Sharpest](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/not_the_sharpest_knife_in_the_drawer) [Knife in the](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=not%20the%20sharpest%20knife%20in%20the%20kitchen) [Kitchen / Drawer](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+the+sharpest+knife+in+the+drawer) ... "  Idiom :
> Not intelligent; dim-witted or prone to stupidity.
> This Idiom is negative in Sense.
> Insulting without Directly saying so.

**With Context 3** :

Can we send X to the Quiz Competition , given his low Marks ?
He is not the Best Student in Class but he is very good at Quizzes !

It is stating that , Considering Studies & among the Class Students , X is neither the Best nor the Worst , here.

Answer (score 0):

It means what it literally says, "he is definitely not the best".

I could not find any authoritative source on it. Colloquially it may mean either "**better than average**" or "**very poor but above rock bottom**".

Utterance with the second meaning is more common and is used when the person saying that is trying to be kind.

Comment: As irony and understatement go, it can well mean below rock bottom, and thus definitely not the best. Similarly, "We are not amused" = We are angry, and you're in deep doodoo.